# eval is not working with variable

Tags: javascript, eval, .post

my problem is eval with variable. I am using $.post this is so good for me. And returning

> **$(#172161616).css("color",'blue');** 
>   or
>   **$(#172161616).css("color",'red');**

this is working i can return this but, how can i run this code in function response.

```
$.post("switch-up-control.php", {
        ip: ip,
        id: sw_id
    }, function(response){
         eval(response);        //i want run code here.
    });
```

error is : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Thanks all.

Comment: Oh my god! Why don't return from server a json and avoid to use `eval()`function(). It is dangerous

Comment: I would suggest having your php file return a json. Something similar to this parhaps: `{ "id": 172161616, "css-property": "color", "css-value": 'red'}`. Then you'll be able to extract the variables and compile the jQuery command without having to resort to a call to the evil `eval` :)

Comment: I must return this ? '{ "id": 172161616, "css-property": "color", "css-value": 'red'}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do seems like a bad idea, but you're getting an error because the code is invalid. There are no quotes around the selectors:

```
$(#172161616).css("color",'blue');
```

this should probably be:

```
$("#172161616").css("color",'blue');
```

Answer (score 0):

As I recommend in my comment, you should return a json from server and use it as variables:

```
$.post("switch-up-control.php", {
    ip: ip,
    id: sw_id
}, function(response){
     $(response.selector).css('color', response.color);
});
```

And the string from server:

```
{selector: '#someselector', color: 'blue'}
```